# Menu menu não está funcionando quando eu clico no toggle-btn

Tags: javascript, html, css

Menu menu não está funcionando,quando eu clico no toggle-btn ele não está chamando o meu menu-config, não está aparecendo

```js
function toggleSidebat(){
    document.getElementById("menu-config").classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#menu-config{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #3589F0;
    left: -200px
}
#menu-config .active{
  left: 0px;
}

#menu-config .toggle-btn{
    background-color: #44bd32;
    position: absolute;
    right: -50px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu-config .toggle-btn img{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 18%;
    top: 18%;
    display: none;
}

#menu-config .toggle-btn:hover img{
transform: rotate(1000grad);
transition: 8s;

}
```

```html
    <div id="menu-config">
    
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebat()">
        <img src="../Imagens/settings.png" alt="">
    </div> 
        
     opa
```

Comment: Detalhe o erro, explique o que está acontecendo.
Assim facilita o entendimento e a resposta.

Comment: quando eu clico no toggle-btn ele não está chamando o meu menu-config, não está aparecendo

Comment: O que vc gostaria que aparecesse ao clicar no botão, a imagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade seu problema é com o CSS e não com o JS

Deixei comentado no CSS, mas nesse estilo a classe tem que estar colada no ID ficando dessa forma `#menu-config.active` isso significa que é o "ID com a classe" se vc deixar separado significa o ID e o elemento dentro com a classe" entende...

Veja seu código funcionando. Na parte do HTML apenas fechei a div do menu que estava a berta. *OBS: Coloquei display:block na imagem para ela aparecer e vc conferir como ficou*

```js
function toggleSidebat(){
            document.getElementById("menu-config").classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#menu-config{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #3589F0;
    left: -200px
}
#menu-config.active{ /* a classe tem que estar unida ao ID */
  left: 0px;
}

#menu-config .toggle-btn{
    background-color: #44bd32;
    position: absolute;
    right: -50px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu-config .toggle-btn img{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 18%;
    top: 18%;
    display: block; /* display: none para esconder a imagem */
}

#menu-config .toggle-btn:hover img{
transform: rotate(1000grad);
transition: 8s;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-config">

    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebat()">
        <img src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" alt="">
    </div> 
        
    opa
</div>
```